# How to execute batch requests in Google Api Java Client (Drive)

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

So, for instance, I am executing multiple requests like this

```
for (final ParentReference previousParent : previousParents) {
    driveService.parents().delete(fileResourceId, previousParent.getId()).execute();
}
```

Is there a way to execute them in a batch (I mean not like adding to a `Collection` and then calling execute on each element)?

If there is, will the batch request form some kind of single request to reduce number of API calls and server requests?

I've seen there is a `BatchRequest` class, but I can't figure if that's what I need and how to use it assuming I have access to `com.google.api.services.drive.Drive` service.

The `BatchRequest` takes two arguments and I can't seem to find how to even build it properly, if that's what I need in first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using a `BatchRequest` will allow you to perform multiple API requests within a simple HTTP request. More information on how to use batching in the Google APIs Java client library is available here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Batch

Comment: Your comment helped me to find example but I'll paste direct link to docs so others don't have to search for it:

https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-java-client/batching.html